# Strange console msg "LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called", only found on an iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use a button to present a `UIActivityViewController` instant. On iPhone I keep receiving a message

> LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called

My code:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:@[string]
                                                    applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                                      animated:YES
                                   completion:nil];
```

I am just using a button to modal the `UIActivityViewController`. I don't receive this error on the simulator.